# Function for adding and removing style on click and unfocus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a function which changes style of element on click and remove it when unfocus. For ex: When element2 is clicked, it should remove class of other elements, and add class to the clicked element only.

```
<div class="dope" id="element777"></div>
<div class="dope" id="element2"></div>
<div class="dope" id="element11"></div>
<div class="dope" id="element245"></div>
<div class="dope" id="element60"></div>
```

.....(More are created automatically, numbers are not estimatable)

I couldnt know the element ids that are created. The only remains same is class.
I have tried this, but its an unprofessional approach.

```
$('#element1').click(function(){

$("#element1").addClass(dope2);
$("#element2").removeClass(dope);
$("#element3").removeClass(dope);
$("#element4").removeClass(dope);

});

$("#element1").blur(function(){
$("#element1").removeClass(dope);
});



$('#element2').click(function(){

$("#element2").addClass(dope2);
$("#element1").removeClass(dope);
$("#element3").removeClass(dope);
$("#element4").removeClass(dope);

});

$("#element2").blur(function(){
$("#element2").removeClass(dope);
});
```

What is the best approach for automating this function, instead of adding click and blur (unfocus) function to ALL of elements ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen for click events on any div with an id containing the word "element', then target its siblings elements (those that are not clicked, without referring to them by id). This might do it:

```
$("div[id*='element']").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('dope').siblings('.dope').removeClass('dope');
});
```

Comment: Nice.  Completely forgot about the *contains* selector!

Comment: I believe the "start with" is actually ^. The * matches anywhere in the string. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: correct me if I wrong, but shouldnt it be addClass('dope2') ?

Comment: Could be, but then I would think you would want to remove dope2 as well from the siblings. How are the .dope and .dope2 classes different? Is there in fact 3 states (.dope, .dope2, and no class)?

Comment: Dope is a class with no border, and dope2 has blue class. If we remove these classes, the design crashes. So we need to change to dope or dope 2.

Comment: so yeah then I would think just don't touch .dope and add/remove .dope2 on click, with the CSS rules that you want, so: $(this).addClass('dope2').siblings('.dope2').removeClass('dope2');

Answer (score 3):

Your jQuery could be vastly simpler if you leverage `this` and [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

Instead of:

```
$("#element1").addClass(dope2);
$("#element2").removeClass(dope);
$("#element3").removeClass(dope);
$("#element4").removeClass(dope);
```

It could be:

```
$('.dope').click(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass(dope2).siblings().removeClass(dope);
    }
);
```

**NOTE:**
 Do you have a variable called `dope` with the class name, or is `dope` the class name?  If it's the classname, you need to put it in quotes: `$(this).addClass('dope2')`, etc.

If you are removing the class `dope`, then will want to add a class you can *always* use to select these elements (so that when you remove `dope`, it continues to work).

Answer (score 1):

Button part:

```
$("div").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("dope") || $(this).hasClass("dope2")){
        $(this).addClass("dope2");
        $(".dope").not($(this)).removeClass("dope");
    }
})
```

Blur part:

```
$("div").blur(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("dope") || $(this).hasClass("dope2")){
        $(this).removeClass("dope");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the :focus css selector rather than using javascript to do what you are doing...  Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp).  Instead of having a click listener, the focus selector will take care of that for you and automatically remove the styling when the element is out of focus.

Comment: Its not an input. Its left side buttons of a chat. see image: http://i.imgur.com/nwdU3pk.jpg

Comment: css is the easiest thing to do, no need to see. But my problem is different. It should unfocus when other button is cliked ONLY.

Comment: In that case, what I would do is add a singular class to all your elements so that you can easily add remove hte other class...i'll show you what i mean.

Comment: actually, legolandbridge has the best solution on here.